# Cast doesn't work as expected when concatenating strings

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to achieve the simplest task - creating the FISCAL_YEAR column as shown below (column YEAR is given):

```
+------+-------------+
| YEAR | FISCAL_YEAR |
+------+-------------+
| 2022 | 2022-2023   |
+------+-------------+
| 2022 | 2022-2023   |
+------+-------------+
| 2022 | 2022-2023   |
+------+-------------+
| 2022 | 2022-2023   |
+------+-------------+
```

I keep getting the error: `can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`

These are the steps I've tried so far, without success:

1. `df['fiscal_year'] = str(df['year']) + "-" + str(df['year']+1)`
2. `df['fiscal_year'] = df['year'].astype(str) + "-" + (df['year']+1).astype(str)`
3. 

`df['year_str'] = pd.Series(df['year'], dtype=pd.StringDtype())`

And also:

`df['year_str'] = df['year'].astype(str)`

And then:

`df['year_str'].str.cat(df['year_str'].astype(int) + 1, sep='-')`

None of these options work. Is there is anything else I'm missing?

** I am on Windows 10 and Python version 3.9.7

Comment: `str(df['year'])` obviously won't work since that's the str of the Series, not a Series of strs. Though maybe you already know that.

Comment: What dtype is `YEAR`? It looks like it's already str, so `df['year']+1` is failing.

Comment: `.str.cat(df['year_str'].astype(int) + 1, ...)` also obviously won't work since you're passing in ints.

Comment: @wjandrea, actually `df['year']+1` in itself works fine. might it be doing an implicit casting? The issue was with the concatenation. The solution of the person below get it to work though. Thanks!

Comment: Implicit casting? in Python? no, never. Python's strongly-typed and Pandas follows that. So if `year` is dtype int, I can't reproduce the issue. Option 2 works perfectly. Make a [mre]; the issue might not be where you expect. Like, you might have made a typo somewhere and don't need to do three casts in the end. See also: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341) and [Why should I post complete errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341)

Comment: As a few comments have hinted, the error is probably because the `YEAR` column is unexpectedly type `str`. If you wrote a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), i.e., including code to construct a minimal, problematic version of `df`, you probably would have discovered this for yourself. Often writing a MVCE for StackOverflow (or a colleague) solves the problem without needing to post the question.

Comment: @Matthias FYI, you can write `[mre]` in a comment and it expands to *[mre]*. More shorthands listed here: [comment formatting help](/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A failproof way could be:

```
df['FISCAL_YEAR'] = (df['YEAR'].astype(str)
                     +'-'+
                     df['YEAR'].astype(int).add(1).astype(str)
                    )
```

Output:

```
   YEAR FISCAL_YEAR
0  2022   2022-2023
1  2022   2022-2023
2  2022   2022-2023
3  2022   2022-2023
```

Comment: This is unbelievably counter-intuitive solution, but it works! Thank you!

Comment: @SAR if you know the original type for sure, you can get rid of either the `.astype(str)` or the `.astype(int)`, one them is useless, which one depends on the original type ;)

Comment: You're right. Removing `astype(str)` from `df['YEAR'].astype(str)` didn't matter and solution still worked fine.